# PowerShell finding duplicates in CSV and outputting different header

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I guess the question is in the title.

I have a CSV that looks something like

```
user,path,original_path
```

I'm trying to find duplicates on the original path, then output both the user and original_path line.

This is what I have so far.

```
$2 = Import-Csv 'Total 20_01_16.csv' | Group-Object -Property Original_path | 
Where-Object { $_.count -ge 2 } | fl Group | out-string -width 500
```

This gives me the duplicates in Original_Path. I can see all the required information but I'll be danged if I know how to get to it or format it into something useful.

I did a bit of Googleing and found this script:

```
$ROWS = Import-CSV -Path 'Total 20_01_16.csv'
$NAMES = @{}
$OUTPUT = foreach ( $ROW in $ROWS ) { 
IF ( $NAMES.ContainsKey( $ROW.Original_path ) -and $NAMES[$ROW.original_path] -lt 2 ) 
{ $ROW }
$NAMES[$ROW.original_path] += 1 }

Write-Output $OUTPUT
```

I'm reluctant to use this because, well first I have no idea what it's doing. So little of the makes any sense to me, I don't like using scripts I can't get my head around.
Also, and this is the more important part, it's only giving me a single duplicate, it's not giving me both sets. I'm after both offending lines, so I can find both users with the same file.

If anyone could be so kind as to lend a hand I'd appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: What output do you need? The original csv-rows for duplicates?

Comment: Pretty much the whole thing.
So if a duplicate is found in Original_Path, I want User,Path,Original_Path

But I need the output for both discoveries.

So if my csv looks like this:

    user,path,original_path
    user1,\\compa\c$\program files\test.doc,\\server1\files\test1.doc
    user2,\\compb\c$\program files\test.doc,\\server1\files\test1.doc

I'll need to know about both user1 and user2, not just user2 which is all I'm getting at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the output format you need, but to build on what you already have we can use this to show the records in the console:

```
Import-Csv 'Total 20_01_16.csv' |
Group-Object -Property Original_path |
Where-Object { $_.count -ge 2 } |
Foreach-Object { $_.Group } |
Format-Table User, Path, Original_path -AutoSize
```

Alternatively, use this to save them in a new csv-file:

```
Import-Csv 'Total 20_01_16.csv' |
Group-Object -Property Original_path |
Where-Object { $_.count -ge 2 } |
Foreach-Object { $_.Group } |
Select User, Path, Original_path |
Export-csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm surprised there's not an option like unix's "uniq -d" that prints out the duplicates.  I also tried "sort -u propertyname" and then doing a diff with the original array, but it didn't work well.

Comment: Jeeze this almost killed my pc for a 430.000.000 line file (not exaggerating, and running 64GB ram). Isn't there something cheaper? The file is already sorted.

Comment: Thousands vs millions lines require different approaches for text reading in general. Look into System.IO.StreamReader + a dictionary/hashset/whatever to quickly lookup duplicates. Ex. of using StreamReader: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119112/filtering-a-log-file-quickly