# Filtering a log file quickly

Tags: algorithm, powershell, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to do some analysis on production log files.

I need to filter roughly 2.5 million lines of text by roughly 50-100 values - potentially 250,000,000 iterations if `O(nm)`.

I've tried `Get-Content | Select-String` but this seems incredibly slow.

Is there *any* way to approach this without iterating over every line once for each value?

### EDIT

So, the log files look a bit like this (datetime : process_id : log_level : message)

```
2016-01-30 14:01:22.349 [ 27]  INFO XXX YYY XXXFX
2016-01-30 14:01:28.146 [ 16]  INFO XXXD YY Z YYY XXXX
2016-01-30 14:01:28.162 [ 16]  DEBUG YY XXXXX YY XX P YYY
2016-01-30 14:01:28.165 [ 16]  DEBUG YY XXXXX YY XX YYY
2016-01-30 14:01:28.167 [ 16]  DEBUG YY XXXXX YY XX YYY
2016-01-30 14:01:28.912 [ 27]  INFO XXX YY XXGXXX YYYYYY YY XX
```

and I may be looking for the values D, F, G and Z.

The values could be strings of binary digits, hexadecimal digits, combinations of the two, strings of regular text and punctuation, or pipe-delimited values.

Comment: "50-100 values" in what format exactly?

Comment: And here I thought they came as wrapped candy ... Do you need to check if the strings exist literally anywhere in the log line? In a particular field? Do you have partial matches (wildcards)? Or regular expressions?

Comment: Can you show us a few examples?

Comment: Sorry lol :)  The logs are production logs - a jumbled mess of messages from anywhere in the code.  Some lines contain IDs of database objects.  I have a list of roughly 10-100 object IDs and I want to find all lines in the logs where those IDs exist.

Comment: Added some more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try a `StreamReader` + `StreamWriter` to speed up reading/writing as `Get-Content` is slow for big files. Also, I would try to make one regex (`word OR word OR word` etc.) to avoid hundreds of iterations. Ex:

```
$words = "foo","bar","donkey" 
#Create regex-pattern (usually faster to match)
$regex = ($words | % { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList "c:\myinputfile.txt"
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList "c:\myOUTputfile.txt"

while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if($line -match $regex) { $writer.WriteLine($line) }
}


#Close writer
$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()

#Close reader
$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()
```

Comment: I much prefer your one-liner for reading from the stream, and the method of making a long, concatenated-literal regex to search each line is brilliant.  Preliminary testing shows the `Where-Object | .Contains` solution taking 5m7s, but this solution taking 1m6s.  Much better!  Tyvm

Answer (score 4):

Rules of thumb:

- `StreamReader` is faster than `Get-Content` is faster than `Import-Csv`.
- String operation is faster than wildcard match is faster than regular expression match.

You probably want something like this if it's sufficient to check whether your log lines contain any of the given strings:

```
$reader  = [IO.StreamReader]'C:\path\to\your.log'
$filters = 'foo', 'bar', ...

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $line = $reader.ReadLine()
  if ($filters | Where-Object {$line.Contains($_)}) {
    $line
  }
}

$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()
```

If you want to use a `StreamWriter` instead of just echoing the output simply adjust the code like this:

```
$reader  = [IO.StreamReader]'C:\path\to\your.log'
$writer  = [IO.StreamWriter]'C:\path\to\output.txt'
$filters = 'foo', 'bar', ...

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $line = $reader.ReadLine()
  if ($filters | Where-Object {$line.Contains($_)}) {
    $writer.WriteLine($line)
  }
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()
```

Depending on the structure of your log lines as well as the filter values and how they need to be applied the filter logic may need adjustments. You need to actually show the log format and filter examples for that, though.

Comment: Maybe add/show instantiation of `$writer` as well, for completeness.

Comment: Narf. Actually I meant to just echo the line, but oh well.

Comment: Thanks, but this takes significantly longer than `Select-String`

Comment: Then the repeated string comparisons take too much time in total. Try the joined regex approach Frode F. suggested.

Comment: Yup, thats much better.  Thanks.